# Require confirmation on correct way

Tags: xml, xslt

I have one question in XSLT. I usually do the following to check for non nullity of variable / node of xml document

```
<Blocks>
   <Block ID="1"/>
   <Block ID="2"/>
   <Block ID="3"/>
 </Blocks>

 <xsl:variable name="var1" select="Blocks/Block[@ID = 1]"/>
 <xsl:if test="$var1 != ''">
   <output>True</output>
 </xsl:if>
```

People in my company say that `$var1 != ''` does not work consistently (means works sometimes and doesnt work sometimes) and not to use such things (but use `test="$var1"`). Require confirmation if this is correct and to use `$var1 != ''` .

Comment: if there are whitespaces and newline characters present in the tag, e.g., `<Block> </Block>`. It will not be empty. Add a `normalize−space()` function to be sure.

Comment: Can you show the code for where you think it works and for where you think it doesn't work. Please include expected output.

Comment: It depends on what you need to check, if you want to check whether any node at all has been selected then check `<xsl:if test="$var1">`, if you want to check whether the selected node contains some content so that the string value is not the empty string then use your check.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want to check is whether the element has a text value or not, e.g. to guard against empty `<Block />` elements, I tend to use the `text()` function rather than a string comparison:

```
<xsl:if test="Blocks/Block[@ID = 1]/text()">
   <output>True</output>
</xsl:if>
```

This expression checks whether the text node exists. Conversely, the string comparison (`= ''`) extracts the string from the text node of the element, and checks whether it's equal to `''`. Theoretically the latter is less efficient than the former, even if the result is equivalent.

(It is possible that XSLT processors and XPath engines may have implemented optimisations for empty string comparison, though).

NOTE: If you want to instruct XSLT to ignore ***insignificant* whitespaces** and only preserve text nodes which contain non-whitespace elements (amongst other criteria defined in the [XSL spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip), you can use the `<xsl:strip-space />` instruction with a configuration like `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>`.

This will safeguard your expression against elements that contain carriage return, linefeeds, tabs, and spaces only (#x20, #x9, #xD or #xA entities).

Comment: Can you show an example where your test will return a result that is different from the result returned by OP's test?

Comment: The OP doesn't require a different result than his/hers. They just require a confirmation whether their method is correct and a suggestion of a possible alternative.

Comment: IMHO, OP asked for confirmation of the claim that their test is inconsistent. Your answer seems to say that it may be, and that your test is somehow better.

Comment: I'm updating my answer to reflect the differences between explicit string comparison and text() node existence.